# "dyld: Symbol not found" in CIFaceFeature using Xcode 5 running on iOS6.1 device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, core-image

I have a project that uses the face detection as provided in CoreImage that was originally developed in Xcode 4.6.3 using the iOS6 SDK with a deployment target of 5.1.  With the release of iOS7 I updated to Xcode5 and the iOS7 SDK keeping the deployment target as 5.1.

This was fine until I added a new class, in Xcode5, that references properties in a CIFaceFeature object, specifically `hasLeftEyePosition`.  The code builds and runs just fine on an iPhone5S running iOS7.02 and an iPod 5th gen running iOS7.02, however when I try to run it in debug on an iPhone4 running iOS6.1 I get the splash screen on the device and then the following output in the console:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_CIFaceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/...
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
 in /var/mobile/Applications/...
```

I have verified that the CoreImage.framework is included to be linked against.  The weird thing about this error is that I access properties of CIFaceFeature objects elsewhere in the code base in files that were added in Xcode 4.6.3.

I have also verified that if I comment out the newly added code accessing `hasLeftEyePosition` the app runs just fine on the iOS6.1 iPhone4.

Does anyone have experience with this type of error?  Is there a setting for the newly added files I need to change to have it link against the correct frameworks?  I'm kind of grasping at straws here as I don't see what the problem is and the fact that I access the exact same property elsewhere in the code with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're referencing the *property* and not the *instance variable*? The error you're seeing is due to a missing instance variable in the iOS 6 version of Core Image. I can see in the iOS 7 headers there is a declared ivar for this which is absent in iOS 6.

If you're doing `feature->hasLeftEyePosition` or similar, you're accessing the instance variable, which should generally be considered an implementation detail you shouldn't use directly. If you're making a subclass and just saying `hasLeftEyePosition`, ditto. You need to be using either `[feature hasLeftEyePosition]` or `feature.hasLeftEyePosition` to use the property.

Comment: I am not subclassing CIFaceFeature and I am using the property via `feature.hasLeftEyePosition`

Comment: @AlexLindblad Then, wow. That makes it seem like clang is optimizing the property access to an instance variable access, which seems impossible and/or very difficult to me. Can you try with optimization turned off? (a.k.a. "Optimization Level" set to None)

Comment: @AlexLindblad Also, just to be sure, can you show us the code you're commenting out which resolves the issue?

Comment: So it turns out I made a mistake.  The code causing the above issue is indeed accessing the ivar as it is in a CIFaceFeature category I created.
'@implementation CIFaceFeature(WRDefaults)

- (id)initWithBounds:(CGRect)bounds_ {
    if (self = [super init]) {
<snip>
        hasLeftEyePosition = TRUE;
<snip>
    }

    return self;
}

@end'
Thank you.